# Visual Studio confusing exception

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, debugging, crash

For a robotics class I'm taking, we have to download the code from http://www.cs.okstate.edu/~katchou/vboost.cpp and place it into a project of the same name. When I debugged the program (by navigating to Debug>StartDebugging in Release mode) I got an error saying :

```
 First-chance exception at 0x6eedfb59 (msvcr100.dll) in vboost.exe: 0xC0000005:
Access   violation reading location 0x415c3a43.
    Unhandled exception at 0x6eedfb59 (msvcr100.dll) in vboost.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation reading location 0x415c3a43.
```

After stopping the debugging process and a window pops up saying:

```
   Unhandled exception at 0x6eedfb59 (msvcr100.dll) in vboost.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation reading location 0x415c3a43.
```

During the debugging without an option to ignore and pressing continue just makes the same window appear again.

Then another c file opens up titled strtol.c and in the "auto" window I notice that the pointer nptr (which is a parameter of the function strtoxl) is given some value and then it says [bad ptr] which I'm assuming means the pointer is bad. Underneath this is an error stating:`Error: expression cannot be evaluated`. The value is not 0 so it isn't NULL. The program stops debugging at line 99 of strol.c.

When I do the same thing in debug mode, the program runs fine until it starts to load the file names of images found in another file. It then exits the program with a 1 instead of the usual 0.

This may seem kind of vague but in all honesty I'm not sure what is going wrong. I tried searching the code I downloaded from that site for the functions strtol or strtoxl, of which neither are present, and I noticed on the call stack that msvcr100.dll seems to be accessing the strtol.c file but I'm not sure why or how. Any help will be appreciated.

Specifics:
Host OS: Ubuntu 10.10
Guest Host: Windows 7 using VirtualBox
Software: Visual Studio 2010 Express

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application requires 5 commandline parameters, and can take 2 optional - it'll crash if you don't pass the first 5.

See lines 364-431 in the cpp file.

1. // Name of the classifier group (i.e., new.clas)
2. // Number of positive images.
3. // Initialize the negative image counter.
4. // Number of classifier levels in the cascade.
5. // Max # of features.
6. (optional) -t, -v, -tab, -mem or -eyefull
7. (optional) -filter

In VS2008 you set these in Project Properties/Debugging/Command Arguments - VS2005/2010 should be same or similar.

Comment: I could have sworn I did this already, but it must have erased the arguments I had input. Thanks so much!

Comment: Just so I know, how did you tell that the arguments weren't being passed. Like what part of the error made you think this, or was it just a most likely error kind of thing?

Comment: @perplexed: I built it and ran it and saw in the debugger where it crashed.

Answer (score 1):

You start the program without providing it with command line arguments it expects and it crashes while trying to access it. Fix the program to be more informative -and/or- pass correct arguments